# Efficiently searching a Linked List of Objects for a String

Tags: c++, search, linked-list

For certain reasons, I have a linked list of objects, with the Object containing a string.

I might be required to search for a particular string, and in doing so, retrieve the object, based on that string.

The starting header of the list is the only input I have for the list.

Though the number of objects I have, is capped at 3000, and that's not so much, I still wondered if there was an efficient way to do this, instead of searching the objects one by one for a matching string.

The Objects in the list are not sorted in any way, and I cannot expect them to be sorted, and the entry point to the linked list is the only input I have.

So, could anyone tell me if there's an efficient way ( search algorithm perhaps ) to achieve this?

Separately for this kind of search, if required, what would be the sort of data structure recommended, assuming that this search be the most data intensive function of the object?

Thanks..

Comment: Unless you are willing to switch to a different data structure, you will be stuck with a linear search for now.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`std::map<std::string, YourObjectType>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/). You can still iterate all objects. But they are sorted by the string now.

If you might have multiple objects with the same string, use a [`multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) instead.

Comment: Possibly difficult for me to change the structure. But I shall explore that possibility. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Having 3000 you would like to use a [`unordered map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of a linked list, which will give you average O(1) lookup, insertion, and deletion time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't switch to any different structure/container, then there is no way to do this better than linear to size of list.